# Jboss how to know which login module suceeded

Tags: java, jboss

I've made a security domain with 2 login module as you can see :

```
 <security-domain name="myDomain" cache-type="default">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="Database" flag="sufficient">
                        <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:/jdbc/hrdb"/>
                        <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select TRIM(CDPASS) from XXXXXXX"/>
                        <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select TRIM(ROLES),'Roles' from XXXXXX"/>
                        <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity" value="guest"/>
                    </login-module>
                    <login-module name="Database-2" code="Database" flag="sufficient">
                        <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:/jdbc/hrdb"/>
                        <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select TRIM(CDPASS) XXXXXX"/>
                        <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select TRIM(ROLES),'Roles' from XXXXXX"/>
                        <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity" value="guest"/>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
```

It correctly log in with both modules but i'd like to know in my java app if there is a way to identify with which module the user connected?